# Why can not I play an audio recorded with AudioRecord on Android?

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord

I need to record an audio on android that I later want to encrypt. So I'm working with the AudioRecord class, since it works the audio at a low level using the bytes directly.

I found a piece of code that works with short and then converts it in to bytes, which is what I want. But once I have created the audio,  I can not play it with any audio player in the phone.

What should I have to do in order for the phone to recognize it as a valid audio file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please forgive me because I really don't remember all in detail, but I had this issue before and I do remember that the audio recorded by AudioRecord has no format, so in order to make it playable you first need to set a format to it, where you have to specify all of the characteristics that you've set up when initializing your AudioRecord instance (such as sample rate, number of channels, etc). I found an example of how to record an audio using AudioRecord and later setting up wav format: https://selvaline.blogspot.com/2016/04/record-audio-wav-format-android-how-to.html I hope it helps.